# Can entities in Google App Engine have the same key name?

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a model called MyModel and I create it like so

```
x = MyModel(key_name = 'hello', parent = parentKey)
```

The question is, is it OK to have another entity with the same key name, but a different parent?

```
z = MyModel(key_name = 'hello', parent = differentParentKey)
```

Comment: the key is not the same... the key_name is

Comment: @aschmid00 I edited the question because it is confusing..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes that's totally fine and you could also consider using the [get_or_insert()](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/modelclass#Model_get_or_insert). But either case that won't be a problem, as long as parents are different.